# How do I include poppler to pyinstaller generated exe when using pdf2image?

Tags: python, pdf, conda, pyinstaller, poppler

I made a simple script that converts pdfs inside the current directory to images. I want to make it into a standalone `.exe` file so that someone who doesn't have python installed on his PC can use it.

The problem is that `pyinstaller` fails to include `poppler` to the exe file so `pdf2image` does not run correctly and the built exe fails. Here's the error message:

> pdf2image.exceptions.PDFInfoNotInstalledError: Unable to get page
> count. Is poppler installed and in PATH? [32024] Failed to execute
> script bulk_pdf2img

I'm currently working on conda environment that has `pyinstaller` and `pdf2image` and `poppler` installed from `conda install` command. It works just fine when I execute the python script from the prompt but when the script is converted to exe, it raises the above error.

I tried the following approaches:

**1. Add `--add-data` option**

I tried to add `poppler` data by doing this.

```
$ pyinstaller --onedir --add-data="C:/Users/myusername/anaconda3/pkgs/poppler-0.89.0-h20e2fe3_4/Library/include/poppler/*;./poppler" bulk_pdf2img.py
```

Doesn't work.

**2. Add `additional-hooks-dir` option**

I added `projectdirectory/hooks/hook-pdf2image.py` that has

```
from PyInstaller.utils.hooks import collect_all

data, binaries, hiddenimports = collect_all('pdf2image')
```

inside and ran

```
$ pyinstaller --onefile --additional-hooks-dir=hooks bulk_pdf2img.py
```

Also doesn't work.

I googled almost every Stackoverflow question that is apparently having the exact same problem as I am but couldn't find any valid solution. What should I do now?

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/lp1hi3/how_do_i_include_nonpython_dependencies_to/

I finally made it work though the solution was a bit ugly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [docs](https://pypi.org/project/pdf2image/)

> You will then have to add the `bin/` folder to `PATH` or use `poppler_path = r"C:\path\to\poppler-xx\bin"` as an argument in `convert_from_path`.

Now, if you are using the `--onefile` option of `pyinstaller` it will unpack all the files into a temporary folder during the execution, you might want to look into this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44352931/14094985) and the related post, to get the path right.

You can do any of the following

- Execute this at the beginning to add the `bin` folder of `poppler` to `PATH`.

  ```py
  os.environ["PATH"]+=os.pathsep+os.path.join('path/to/poppler','bin')
  ```
- ```py
  pdf2image.convert_from_path('path/to/pdf',poppler_path=r"path\to\poppler\bin")
  ```

Comment: Thanks! Yeah the PATH was a big problem for me because pdfinfo.exe was NOT able to find related .dll files when I set the argument `poppler_path=r"C:\path\to\poppler-xx\bin"`. It doesn't work if you only specify pdfinfo.exe's bin/ location.

Comment: I kind-of resolved it with an ugly way of manually copy-pasting all .dll files from `C:\Users\my_username\anaconda3\envs\my_envname\Library\bin` but in the future, I'll try your way of setting PATH env variable in the runtime.